# Windows service with webbrowser control does not print when deployed

Tags: c#, printing, webbrowser-control

I've developed a windows services that checks a directory every x time and, if html files are present, they are sent to the printer.
Everything works fine on my PC, but when the application was deployed on a server PC, it doesn't  print.
For the implementation I used this link as a reference: https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/using-the-webbrowser-control-to-print-documents/.
Through logging, I know that the event ie.PrintTemplateInstantiation is called. After that, nothing is logged anymore, no errors. What could be wrong?

All relevant code:

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(PrintDocument);
  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  thread.Start();
```

---

```
private void PrintDocument()
  {
     try
     {
        var printJob = _printJobs.First(x => !x.Printed);
        new Print.Print().StartDocumentPrint(_printerName, printJob, PrintFinished);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // Some logging
     }
   }
```

---

```
      public void StartDocumentPrint(string pname, PrintJob file, Action<PrintJob> finished)
  {
     _file = file;
     _finishedAction = finished;

     try
     {
        // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
        var webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

        // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
           new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

        // Set the Url property to load the document.
        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(file.File);

        Application.Run();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // Logging
     }
  }
```

---

```
private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
     var logService = DependencyResolver.Container.Resolve<ILogService>();
     WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;

     try {
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)(wb.ActiveXInstance);

        ie.PrintTemplateInstantiation +=
          new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateInstantiationEventHandler(IE_OnPrintTemplateInstantiation);

        ie.PrintTemplateTeardown +=
          new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(IE_OnPrintTemplateTeardown);

        ie.PutProperty("WebBrowserControl", (object)wb);

       wb.Print();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

        // Logging
     }
  }
```

---

```
private static void IE_OnPrintTemplateInstantiation(object pDisp)
  {
     // Logging
  }
```

---

```
private static void IE_OnPrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
  {
     // Logging

     _finishedAction.Invoke(_file);

     SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 iwb2 = pDisp as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2;
     WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)(iwb2.GetProperty("WebBrowserControl"));

     wb.Dispose();

     Application.ExitThread();  
  }
```

Comment: Just a guess, but could this have to do with the permissions of the user account under which the service is running?

Comment: Or perhaps this?  https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/

Comment: Using the same service images are printed (on a different printer) so I don't think permissions have anything to do with it.

Comment: Microsoft does not support running MSHTML in Windows service.

Comment: Then how come I can install the service on my PC and run it without problems? Maybe there is a difference in a regular Windows and Windows Server?